# How to launch 4 instances on Amazon for Spark cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, apache-spark

I tried to launch Hadoop Spark cluster on Amazon EC2 (spot instances). I selected m4.large instance and selected 4 instances. But when I created it, I got just 2 instances launched. What's the problem? Region: us-west-2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spot instance capacity is not guaranteed. It is likely only two `m4.large` instances were available that satisfied your bid. Modify your launch configuration:

- To use on-demand instances to guarantee four instances but you will be paying a lot more
- Increase your bid amount for spots
- Use a mix of on-demand and spot